# Cinnamon dark theme has pale-on-paler text on buttons

Tags: cinnamon

I'm trying to use a dark theme in Cinnamon but the buttons don't look right because the background is too similar to the the text colour.

I would like to make the background dark and the text white.

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image: button]